# Email formal way to express that you are ready to share information

Tags: phrase-request, formal-language, email

I am requested some explanations on some topic in professional email exchanges, and I don't know if I can end the mail with :

"Please do not hesitate to contact me for further information".

Actually I am French and I use here a kind of translated expression often used in French.

I would like to know if it sounds good enough for a professional email in English, or is there a better way to express this idea that I am ready to provide more explanations if it is needed.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect.